# File behaves differently when loaded from jar or directory

Tags: java, jar, applet

I'm a java newbie with a real hair puller. Hope someone can help.

I have a binary file that loads ok from the applet's directory,
but which only partially loads from the applet's jar file.

The code below loads the file both ways and compares them. They
should be identical, but the output is "divergence at byte 8181".

```
int spx_data_length = 158994;
byte[] spx_buf  = new byte[spx_data_length];
byte[] spx_buf2 = new byte[spx_data_length];

// binary file in jar
InputStream is = Vocals.class.getResourceAsStream("0.raw");
is.read(spx_buf, 0, spx_data_length);
is.close();

// same binary file in applet directory
URL srcURL=new URL(getCodeBase(),"0.raw");
URLDataSource u_dat = new URLDataSource(srcURL);
is=u_dat.getInputStream();
is.read(spx_buf2, 0, spx_data_length);
is.close();

// compare them
for(int i=0;ispx_data_length;i++){
  if(spx_buf[i] != spx_buf2[i]){
    Obj[0]="divergence at byte "+i;  win.call("show_string", Obj);
    i=spx_data_length;
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, unpack it from jar and compare it with original.

Comment: How did you get `spx_data_length`? Not hard-coded?

Comment: The file extracted from the jar is identical to the source file, and the file length is hardcoded and about 300k.

Comment: I loaded the file both ways and compared them byte by byte. The files diverged at the 8181 byte. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) will read *up to* `spx_data_length` bytes, but may very well read less. Particularly in the case of compressed data (i.e. reading from the JAR), it might return one decompression buffer worth of data at a time. You should either loop until the read returns `-1`, or use something like [`DataInputStream.readFully(byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). And you should compare the number of bytes read: if that differes, there is little point in comparing the bytes past the smaller of these counts.

Comment: That was the trick. Thanks. I shouldn't have assumed that the two read functions behaved the same.